# Differences between rdf:resource, rdf:about and rdf:ID

Tags: xml, rdf

What are the conceptual differences between `rdf:resource`, `rdf:about`, and `rdf:ID`. I did some investigation but the difference between them are not clear for me yet. For example, whether `rdf:ID` is used when declaring a resource for the first time, `rdf:resource` is used for referencing an already existing resource, etc.

I would be glad if you provide some little examples.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To be clear this is only about a particular way of writing rdf: namely RDF/XML. Other syntaxes don't feature these differences.

With that disclaimer out of the way:

What we're trying to do is write statements of the form:

```
subject predicate object
```

and in particular:

```
subjectURI predicate objectURI
```

So how do we introduce subject and object URIs in RDF/XML?

1. `rdf:about` sets the subject URI of a statement, which may be absolute (`http://example.com/`) or resolved relative to the BASE of the document (e.g. `/foo/bar`, `#frag`). (Like `href` in html)
2. `rdf:resource` sets the object URI of a statement, once again either absolute or relative.
3. `rdf:ID` sets the subject URI, but it can only be within this document. An ID can also only be used once. Very like `<a name="baz">` or `id="baz"` in html.

`rdf:ID` is discouraged since

1. you can replace it with an `rdf:about` or `rdf:resource` with a fragment `#baz` and
2. it can cause xml issues if you use the same id more than once.

That is, it's redundant and a potential source of errors.

In retrospect there typically only needs to be one attribute to specify a URI, since whether something is a subject or object is apparent from the RDF/XML syntax:

```
<ex:Foo ...> - subject
  <ex:prop ... /> - property then object
</ex:Foo>

<ex:Foo ...> - subject
  <ex:prop> - property
    <ex:Bar ... /> - subject (and implictly an object chaining from previous) 
...
```

(rule of thumb: odd lines `rdf:about`, even lines, `rdf:resource`)

and using both `rdf:about` and `rdf:resource` on an element is almost always an error (you're either in a subject position or object position).

#### tl;dr

Avoid `rdf:ID`. Use `rdf:about` and `rdf:resource` much like an href, the former for subject, the latter for objects.

#### Additional

Forgot to mention that `rdf:ID` can be used on a property element, but it does something you may find unexpected: it reifies the triple. Avoid `rdf:ID`.

Comment: Just edited to fix some errors, and fudge a little. RDF/XML is a bit nasty, and I'd avoid it if you're new to RDF. Use a syntax like n-triples or turtle where the mapping to the RDF model is much simpler. You can always convert to RDF/XML using a tool like rapper.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to clarify a few of the excellent points in the provided answer, but only with respect to rdf:ID and rdf:about.

The tags are used to build a URI. If the full URI is not provided (such as rdf:ID="x"), then the generated URI is relative to the in-scope base URI usually derived from the document's location, but it can be specified with the xml:base attribute.

The point (mentioned above) is that rdf:about may be a fully qualified URI, so it is easy to just set it.

rdf:ID cannot be a fully qualified URI, but, you can still control that if you manually set the xml:base attribute.

The general rule of thumb for me, therefore, is to use rdf:about for a "globally known" identifier (when you want the URI to always be the same) and to use rdf:ID when describing a local resource whose URI is not cared about outside of the current document.