# Jena RDF resource URI with fragment

Tags: rdf, jena

I have a problem when reading RDF-XML into a Jena model. I use

```
FileManager fileManager = FileManager.get();
Model model = fileManager.loadModel(url);
```

Resource URIs like

**http://kulturarvsdata.se/resurser/aukt/geo/county#01**

turn out like

**http://kulturarvsdata.se/resurser/aukt/geo/01**

in the resources in the Jena model, i.e. the URI fragment part is stripped away.

I have tried to provide the base URI ecplicitly to Jena:

```
Model model = fileManager.loadModel(url, "http://kulturarvsdata.se/resurser/aukt/geo/county#", "RDF/XML");
```

but that makes no difference.

Have I misunderstiod something or is there a way to convince Jena to preserve the URI fragments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that base URI doesn't work like prefixes in turtle and SPARQL.

http://kulturarvsdata.se/resurser/aukt/geo/county begins:

```
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://kulturarvsdata.se/resurser/aukt/geo/county#">
    ...
```

You then have a resource:

```
   <County rdf:about="01">...
```

That `rdf:about` URI is resolved relative to the provided base `http://kulturarvsdata.se/resurser/aukt/geo/county#`. And note I said 'resolved' rather than 'concatenated' which is what prefixes do. Resolving `01` relative to the base gives `http://kulturarvsdata.se/resurser/aukt/geo/01`.

The fragment (`#`) at the end of base does nothing in practice. What you need to do is replace your abouts with:

```
<County rdf:about="#01">...
```

(Essentially you can't use document base to make all links internal. Internal links must use fragments)

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense. I'll pass this on to the people who manage the dataset.

Comment: Minor update, I downloaded the resources and played around, the suggestion worked for resources using rdf:about. Interestingly enough, those using rdf:ID needed the original setup, with the fragment mark in xml:base. I assume there is something buried in the specs that explains why...

Comment: Oh yes, rdf:ID will work (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118326/differences-between-rdfresource-rdfabout-and-rdfid/7119042#7119042). You don't need the fragment in base, however.

Comment: Oh well, there I learned something new! I had got an altogether incorrect impression of the semantics of rdf:ID in the first place.