# what does a hashtag mean before a resource ID in RDF and OWL

Tags: rdf, owl

I often see a hashtag in front of resources names in RDF serialization of OWL. For instance:

```
....rdf:resource="#hasParent" />
```

What does this mean? When I look it up, Google gives me a bunch of stuff about twitter. :)

Comment: In talking about IRIs (and URLs, URIs, URNs, &c.), it's typically called a fragment identifier.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118326/differences-between-rdfresource-rdfabout-and-rdfid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is specific to RDF/XML. Here, you have a *relative* IRI which must be completed with the `xml:base` given in the document to form the *absolute* IRI that identifies the resource. In RDF and OWL, everything is identified by absolute IRIs only. Apart from that, it does not have any particular meaning. However, it is convenient to use IRIs with a hash for Linked Data: the IRI will dereference to the base IRI, which is typically identifying the document that describes the full IRI.

For instance, take the SKOS ontology:

```
<rdf:RDF ...
  xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core">
 ...
<rdf:Description rdf:about="#Concept">
 ...
</rdf:Description>
 ...
```

It defines the term `http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept`. If you use this IRI in a HTTP GET request, with a header `Accept: application/rdf+xml`, you will find the RDF/XML serialisation of the SKOS ontology, in which the term is defined and described.